# How to remove all oracle java using powershell

Tags: powershell

I wanted to start by saying i did read some other topics on this but at this point i still have to do it none the less (decision been made above my pay grade).

We are in the process of moving and testing out Azul java to see how well that works for us. Meantime I need to figure out how to script the uninstall of the all Oracle java (preferably I would have a script for JRE and another for JDK).

Currently how I have been removing java versions is by having a list of all jre versions doing `msiexec /x "GUID of the java version" /qn` but it is incredibly time consuming so I wanted to get those strings pragmatically.

Right now I run the following command:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'Java*'}
```

[image]

However, I am trying to find out how to automatically get the IdentifyNumber for every result as long as Vendor = Oracle Corporation and pipe it to the msiexec command to problematically remove them. Azul is installed on the same system as the command is being ran but is not showing up (which is good but just in case I wanted to have the vendor qualifier).

My question is: Can someone help me pipe the IdentifyNumber of the product into msiexec command assuming Vendor is Oracle Corporation

Thank you in advance.

Update 1: 
Following feedback from Drew and Ansgar

```
$Source = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
$Uninstall = $Source | Where-Object {($_.Publisher -like '*Oracle*')-and ($_.DisplayName -like 'Java*')} | select UninstallString
$UninstallString = $Uninstall.UninstallString
$UninstallSting | ForEach-Object{Invoke-Expression -ScriptBlock ($UninstallString)}
```

However, I cant seem to pipe the strings correctly as I keep getting:

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' required by parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Specified method 
is not supported.
At C:\Konstantin\Java\UninstallAllJava.ps1:8 char:62
+ ... ting | ForEach-Object{Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ($UninstallString)}
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: [Win32_Product is evil](https://gregramsey.net/2012/02/20/win32_product-is-evil/). Do not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to figure it out so here is what I came up with which seem to work

> Set "Source" variable to registry location

```
$Source = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
```

> Set "Uninstall" variable to inherit from source and reduce the scope to Oracle and Java

```
$Uninstall = $Source | Where-Object {($_.Publisher -like '*Oracle*')-and ($_.DisplayName -like 'Java*')} | select UninstallString
```

> Set "UninstallString" variable to get only the uninstall string from "Uninstall" variable

```
$UninstallStrings = $Uninstall.UninstallString -replace "MsiExec.exe ","MsiExec.exe /qn " -replace "/I","/X"
```

> Run all the uninstall strings

```
ForEach($UninstallString in $UninstallStrings){& cmd /c "$UninstallString"}
```

I am sure it can be a lot cleaner but this is the best i can do for now. For some versions of java the uninstall strings would give /i variable instead of /x (JDK 6) which is why i had to do the second replace statement.

Example:

```
UninstallString                                     
---------------                                     
MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F03217079FF}
MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83216045FF}
MsiExec.exe /I{32A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0160450}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the Registry method.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
Where-Object {$_.Publisher -like '*oracle*'} | select UninstallString
```

This will give you your `MsiExec.exe` link. E.G. `MsiExec.exe /X{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F32180181F0}`

Comment: Following your example I have the following: <blink>$Source = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* $Uninstall = $Source | Where-Object {($_.Publisher -like '*Oracle*')-and ($_.DisplayName -like 'Java*')} | select UninstallString $UninstallString = $Uninstall.UninstallString $UninstallSting | ForEach-Object{Invoke-Expression -ScriptBlock ($UninstallString)} <blink> but the last part where i try to run each string keeps failing and i cant figure out why