# Run command If fails then run the other one if success then end

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I'm trying to find a way to uninstall maya2019 from all studio workstation. We have 3 versions of maya2019 with different uninstall commands:

```
"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\Setup\Setup.exe" /P {D4BE10F2-3E2D-4120-863A-765623D53264} /M MAYA /LANG en-us /q

"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\Setup\Setup.exe" /P {77067FD9-800C-48B4-803D-569642ADABC5} /M MAYA /LANG en-us /q

"C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\Setup\Setup.exe" /P {1DB1AEB7-EDBD-4BB1-87DB-26C72576DA42} /M MAYA /LANG en-us /q
```

I need to make a script that runs the commands, if one fails then it runs the the next one down, if it succeed the it exits with complete and stops.

Right now I have this:

```
if "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\Setup\Setup.exe" /P {D4BE10F2-3E2D-4120-863A-765623D53264} /M MAYA /LANG en-us /q; then
    echo success && exit
else
if "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\Setup\Setup.exe" /P {77067FD9-800C-48B4-803D-569642ADABC5} /M MAYA /LANG en-us /q; then
    echo success && exit
else
if "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\Setup\Setup.exe" /P {77067FD9-800C-48B4-803D-569642ADABC5} /M MAYA /LANG en-us /q; then
    echo success && exit
```

but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are those guids (`{D4BE10F2-3E2D-4120-863A-765623D53264}`) something you can find in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`? If that is the case, possibly a property called `UninstallString` can be found there with the command to uninstall the appropriate version.

Comment: What happens when this is run?

Comment: Using WMI, or, _as already suggested_, the registry, to determine the GUID, or directly uninstall, based upon the known strings is how I'd recommend you do this. Running any one of three possible options, looks just so lazy/inefficient.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the late reply. yes the guids are from the registry may problems was finding a way to check this and call it out. mklement0 this is exactly what I was looking for but unfortunately did not know where to start, I'll be looking at the cod you gave closely so I understand, it'll help me create more uninstall scrips later on

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Alan. I've added some explanation to my answer; to pursue the more robust and efficient registry-based approach, I suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53490472/45375; if that doesn't help, I suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) in the comments on the question, a more efficient solution would be to query the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` for uninstallation command lines based on the GUIDs in your commands.

<sup>[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53490472/45375) provides pointers as to how to do that.</sup>

If that is not an option, here'a PowerShell solution:

```
foreach ($guid in '{D4BE10F2-3E2D-4120-863A-765623D53264}', 
                  '{77067FD9-800C-48B4-803D-569642ADABC5}', 
                  '{1DB1AEB7-EDBD-4BB1-87DB-26C72576DA42}') {

  $exe = 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2019\Setup\Setup.exe'

  $ps = Start-Process -PassThru -Wait $exe "/P $guid /M MAYA /LANG en-us /q"

  if ($ps.ExitCode -eq 0) { "Success"; exit 0 }

}

Write-Warning "Uninstallation failed."
exit $ps.ExitCode
```

`Start-Process -PassThru -Wait` starts the installer process, waits for its termination, and then returns a [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instance representing the terminated process, whose exit code (`.ExitCode`) can then be examined. An exit code of `0` signals success, any other value failure.